The values on Borel sets of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure induced by a probability density function
Let $ \rho $ be a scalar probability density, i.e., a function $ \rho\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R $ such that

$ \rho(t)\geqq 0 $ for every $ t\in \mathbb R $;
$ \int_{\mathbb R}\rho(t)\,\mathrm dt = 1 $.

It's kinda easy to prove that
$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x\rho(t)\,\mathrm dt
$$
gives a probability distribution function, i.e., a function $ F\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R $ that is

monotonically increasing;
right-continuous;
such that $ \lim_{x\to -\infty}F(x) = 0 $ and $ \lim_{x\to +\infty}F(x) = 1 $;

and it's a standard fact then that there exists a unique Borel measure $ \mu_F $ on $ \mathbb R $ that satisfies
$$
\mu_F(\left]a,b\right]) = F(b) - F(a)
$$
whenever $ a,b\in \mathbb R $ and $ a < b $, i.e., the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure induced by the distribution function $ F $.
I was wondering, how can I prove that
$$
\mu_F(A) = \int_A\rho(t)\,\mathrm dt
$$
for a Borel subset $ A\subset \mathbb R $?
I thought that maybe one could hope to write $ A $ as a (disjoint, countable) union of intervals and then use some telescopic sum trick, but this is definitely not the case.

Since $\mu_F$ is determined by the measure it assigns to $(a,b]$, then you only need check your formula holds for $(a,b]$. Then check that $A\mapsto \int_A \rho(t),dt$ defines a measure.

You know that
$$\nu: \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,1], \ A \mapsto \int_{A} \rho(t)dt$$ defines a probability measure. It satisfies
$$\nu((a,b]) = \int_{a}^{b}\rho(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{b}\rho(t)dt - \int_{-\infty}^{a}\rho(t)dt = F(b)-F(a)$$
for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$. Since $\mu_F$ is the unique measure with this property it must be $\mu_F = \nu$.
